# How can I crop a 1920x1200 monitor to 1920x1080?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, monitors, xrandr, kubuntu

I have just purchased a 1920x1200 monitor, and have some situations where I want to force the output to the more common 1920x1080. However, I don't want to distort the output, and would prefer a "cropping" black bar at the bottom.

[Some](https://superuser.com/questions/248840/limit-video-output-to-a-section-of-a-display-and-leave-the-rest-blank) have suggested using `xrandr` `fb` and `transform` in the general case, but I cannot understand how `transform` works. Is this approach suitable for my case, and if so, what command would I use?

==EDIT==

From `man xrandr`

```
   --transform a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
          Specifies a transformation matrix to apply on the  output.  Automati‐
          cally  a  bilinear  filter is selected.  The mathematical form corre‐
          sponds to:
                 a b c
                 d e f
                 g h i
          The transformation is based on homogeneous  coordinates.  The  matrix
          multiplied  by  the  coordinate vector of a pixel of the output gives
          the transformed coordinate vector of a pixel in the  graphic  buffer.
          More precisely, the vector (x y) of the output pixel is extended to 3
          values (x y w), with 1 as the w coordinate and multiplied against the
          matrix. The final device coordinates of the pixel are then calculated
          with the so-called homogenic division by the  transformed  w  coordi‐
          nate.   In  other words, the device coordinates (x' y') of the trans‐
          formed pixel are:
                 x' = (ax + by + c) / w'   and
                 y' = (dx + ey + f) / w'   ,
                 with  w' = (gx + hy + i)  .
          Typically, a and e corresponds to the scaling on the X and Y axes,  c
          and  f  corresponds to the translation on those axes, and g, h, and i
          are respectively 0, 0 and 1. The matrix can also be used  to  express
          more  complex  transformations  such as keystone correction, or rota‐
          tion.  For a rotation of an angle T, this formula can be used:
                 cos T  -sin T   0
                 sin T   cos T   0
                  0       0      1
          As a special argument, instead of passing a matrix, one can pass  the
          string none, in which case the default values are used (a unit matrix
          without filter).
```

Comment: I had some luck using just `xrandr --fb` here, but (a) it's documented not to work and (b) it caused all sorts of weirdness... but maybe it'll work for you...

Comment: @derobert Actually, it does work somewhat! I think I didn't have my parameters around the right way before. Sometimes it works perfectly; sometimes, instead of having a black rectangle on the bottom of the screen, I have rubbish (e.g. some screen from another virtual desktop) that I can't get rid of. Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: Well, it works better for you than me, then. It caused all kinds of weird issues for me. The docs say its not supposed to work at all...

Comment: Actually, having tested a bit more, it doesn't work, at least in Kubuntu 13.10 (KDE 4.12.3). The bottom 120 pixels are indeed removed, but my DE panel at the bottom of the screen is missing. Then, after alt-tabbing, my windows become vertically squashed, and my mouse-clicks correspond to different (unsquashed) positions.